# AT command to send messages from my phone

Tags: sms, nokia, at-command, hyperterminal

I connected my Nokia 5235 to my pc. I want to send messages by using AT commands from hyperterminal. Is it possible ? What all the settings i need to do for that?

regards
Parvathi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that particular handset supports it, but the commands you need are:

- AT+CMGW - write a message to local storage
- AT+CMGS - send a message
- AT+CMGF - select format for messages (PDU mode or text mode).

The normal syntax would be like this:

```
AT+CMGF=0 [PDU mode]
OK
AT+CMGS=79 [send a message of 79 bytes]
>
[79 bytes of PDU data terminated with ctrl-Z]
OK
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.This commands are for sending message by using GSM modem, right?. Is it possible to send messages by using handset?

Comment: @Paru, I don't quite understand what you're asking. In this instance the handset is acting as a "GSM modem", if you want to call it that.